# How to check specific word in whole string at specific index in the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, find

I would like to handle following scenraio in the array of objects to check whether the string contain specific word. I would like to make sure the position of the word for checking. Below is the example

```js
let array = [
   {
      "val":"test1-test3"
   },
   {
      "val":"test1-test2-test3"
   },
   {
      "val":"test1-test4-test3"
   },
   {
      "val":"test1-test2-test4-test3"
   },
   {
      "val":"test1-test2"
   },
   {
      "val":"test1-test4-test2-test3"
   }
]
```

**Scenarios**

1. I would like to check if the string contains a test2 or not.
2. If the string contains a test2, I would like to make sure at which position the test2 appears.
3. It can appear in the first and last positions.
4. If it appears in between the first(first 3 letters) and last position (last 3 letters) I would like to set that value as false.

**Expected output:**

output = [false,true,false,true,false,true]

Comment: For #3, do you mean "cannot appear in first or last pos"? Else why is `"test1-test2"` false? If so, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `array.map((a) => a.val.includes("test2") && !a.val.startsWith("test2") && !a.val.endsWith("test2"));`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. it is false because if it is not there in string then I don't want to check the condition at all.

Comment: But it is there in the string: "test1-test2". Isn't it?

Comment: sorry I understood wrong. I have made false for where test2 is not appearing, appearing at first or at last .

Comment: Ok, then my first comment should work. Or here's a more efficient one: `array.map((a) => { const i = a.val.indexOf("test2); return i > 0 && i < a.val.length - "test2".length;});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    val: "test1-test3",
  },
  {
    val: "test1-test2-test3",
  },
  {
    val: "test1-test4-test3",
  },
  {
    val: "test1-test2-test4-test3",
  },
  {
    val: "test1-test2",
  },
  {
    val: "test1-test4-test2-test3",
  },
];

const res = arr.map(({ val }) => {
  const tests = val.split`-`;
  const idx = tests.findIndex((item) => item === "test2");  
  return idx > 0 && idx < tests.length - 1;
});

console.log("res", res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce:

```js
let array = [{
    "val": "test1-test3"
}, {
    "val": "test1-test2-test3"
}, {
    "val": "test1-test4-test3"
}, {
    "val": "test1-test2-test4-test3"
}, {
    "val": "test1-test2"
}, {
    "val": "test1-test4-test2-test3"
}];

const contains = array.reduce((akku, item, index) => {
    const words = item.val.split('-');
    const foundIndex = words.indexOf('test2');
    akku[index] = (foundIndex > 0 && foundIndex < words.length - 1);
    return akku;
}, []);
console.log(contains);
```

Comment: Hi Arthur, can you please help me with this ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67576933/javascript-how-to-map-two-javascript-object-to-get-the-output-which-map-the-id