# JavaScript: How to map two objects to get the output which map the Id of first object to the name of other object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I am trying to make a function that maps the data2 object value to the name of the data1.

I tried to iterate data2 object2 with data1 but it is not working properly. I am able to map them but not getting the value of data1 when it is not there in data2.

Is there any way I can map properly to get the desired output mentioned in the code?

```js
let data1 = {
    attributes: [{
            Id: 'test1',
            Name: 'Test1',
            Type: 'date'
        },
        {
            Id: 'test2',
            Name: 'Test2',
            Type: 'string'
        },
        {
            Id: 'test3',
            Name: 'Test3',
            Type: 'string'
        },
        {
            Id: 'test4',
            Name: 'Test4',
            Type: 'boolean'
        }
    ]
};

let data2 = {
    value: [{
            test1: '10-12-2021',
            test2: '4',
            dummy: 'ignore me'
        },
        {
            test3: '3',
            test4: true,
            abc: 'ignore me'
        },
        {
            test1: '12-12-2023',
            test3: '42',
            dummy1: 'ignore me'
        }
    ]
};

//output

let ouput = {
    rows: [{
            Test1: '10/12/2021',
            Test2: '4',
            Test3: '',
            Test4: ''
        },
        {
            Test1: '',
            Test2: '',
            Test3: '3',
            Test4: 'Y'
        },
        {
            Test1: '12/12/2023',
            Test2: '',
            Test3: '42',
            Test4: ''
        }
    ]
};

//function

function mapper(data1, data2) {
    let formattedValue = [];
    data2.value.forEach(val => {
        let data = {};
        for (let prop in val) {
            let name;
            const filter = data1.attributes.filter(el => el.Id === prop)[0];
            if (filter) {
                name = filter.Name;
                switch (filter.Type) {
                    case 'boolean':
                        data[name] =
                            val[prop] === true ? 'Y' : val[prop] === false ? 'N' : '';
                        break;
                    case 'date':
                        data[name] = new Date(val[prop]).toLocaleDateString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        data[name] = val[prop];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        formattedValue.push(data);
    });

    return formattedValue;
}

console.log(mapper(data1, data2));
```

same if I pass data2 as empty value I am looking to get below output

```js
let data1 = {
  attributes: [
    {
      Id: 'test1',
      Name: 'Test1',
      Type: 'string'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test2',
      Name: 'Test2',
      Type: 'string'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test3',
      Name: 'Test3',
      Type: 'string'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test4',
      Name: 'Test4',
      Type: 'boolean'
    }
  ]
};

let data2 = {
  value: [
  ]
};

//output

let ouput = {
  rows: [
    {
      Test1: '',
      Test2: '',
      Test3: '',
      Test4: ''
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const data1 = {attributes:[{Id:'test1',Name:'Test1',Type:'date'},{Id:'test2',Name:'Test2',Type:'string'},{Id:'test3',Name:'Test3',Type:'string'},{Id:'test4',Name:'Test4',Type:'boolean'}]}
      data2 = {value:[{test1:'10-12-2021',test2:'4'},{test3:'3',test4:true},{test1:'12-12-2023',test3:'42'}]};
      data3 = {value: []}

const mapper = (x, y) => {
  const row = x.attributes.map(e => [e.Id, e.Name])
        format = e => { switch (true) {
            case typeof e === 'boolean':
              return e ? 'Y' : 'N'
            case isNaN(e) && !isNaN(Date.parse(e)):
              return new Date(e).toLocaleDateString()
            default: return e
          }}
  const rows = (y.value.length ? y.value : [1]).map(e => 
     Object.fromEntries(row.map(([k, v]) => [v, format(e[k]) ?? '']))
  )
  return { rows }
} 

console.log(mapper(data1, data2))
console.log(mapper(data1, data3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation:**

> `y.value.length ? y.value : [1]`

Checks if `data.value` is empty, if not returns `data.value`. If yes returns `array` with 1 element (can be any value, it is just needed to do 1 iteration to meet your requirement about empty data, so value doesn't really matter here.

Rest of code should be pretty clear, if not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I need to add more type support for data1 attributes? How we can support multiple types such as date or integer?

Comment: for example I would like to current date format to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @Bravo Does it fit your requirements now? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

because you want minimum one set of values even `data2.values` is empty.  My already given solution will work if we add empty object when array is empty, so adding below will fix it.

```
// I had to add below lines to get your desired result
// if `data2.value` is empty array
const arrayToLoop = [...data2.value];  
if(arrayToLoop.length === 0) {
  arrayToLoop.push({});
}
```

and now we will loop variable `arrayToLoop` rather than `data2.value`

also wrote small function used to convert the value as per given type, you can extend it as per your own need

```
function parseValue(type, value){
    if(value.length==0){
      return '';
    }
    switch(type.toLowerCase()){
      case 'boolean':
        return value === true ? 'Y' : value === false ? 'N' : '';
      case 'date':
        return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString();        
      default:
        return value;
    }
}
```

---

first I will get all the key and label mapping, and will look all the values for each key.
notice how I done below.

let me know if you face any prob.

```js
function parseValue(type, value){
    if(value.length==0){
      return '';
    }
    switch(type.toLowerCase()){
      case 'boolean':
        return value === true ? 'Y' : value === false ? 'N' : '';
      case 'date':
        return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString();        
      default:
        return value;
    }
}

function BusinessObjectMapper(data1, data2){
  const arrayToLoop = [...data2.value];  
  if(arrayToLoop.length === 0) {
      arrayToLoop.push({});
  }

  const rows = arrayToLoop.map(v=>{
     let r = {};
     data1.attributes.forEach(o=>{
      let {Id, Name, Type} = o;
      r[Name]=parseValue(Type, v[Id]||'');
     })
     return r;
  })
  
  return {
    rows
  };
}

let data1 = {
  attributes: [
    {
      Id: 'test1',
      Name: 'Test1',
      Type:'string'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test2',
      Name: 'Test2',
      Type:'boolean',
    },
    {
      Id: 'test3',
      Name: 'Test3',
      Type:'date'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test4',
      Name: 'Test4',
      Type:'un-known',
    }
  ]
};

let data2 = {
  value: [
    {
      test1: '1',
      test2: true
    },
    {
      test3: '02/02/2020',
      test4: '42'
    },
    {
      test1: 'deepak',
      test3: '01/01/2021'
    }
  ]
};

let data2_empty = {
  value: []
}

console.log(BusinessObjectMapper(data1, data2));
console.log(BusinessObjectMapper(data1, data2_empty));
```

Comment: Thanks, Deepak. It is failing when data2 has empty values.let data1 = {
  attributes: [
    {
      Id: 'test1',
      Name: 'Test1'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test2',
      Name: 'Test2'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test3',
      Name: 'Test3'
    },
    {
      Id: 'test4',
      Name: 'Test4'
    }
  ]
};

let data2 = {
  value: [
    }
  ]
};

//output

let ouput = {
  rows: [
    {
      Test1: '',
      Test2: '',
      Test3: '',
      Test4: ''
    },
  ]
};

Comment: I also modified question to support type

Comment: actually your data2 is incorrect its not proper object it should be  `{ value: [ {} ] };`  notice `value` is an `array` that can empty object so `{}` rather than single `{`  hope its clear now?

Comment: My bad. data2 will be {value:[ ]} and I modified question little bit to support different types. Is it possible to update the solution?

Comment: @Bravo you can try my updated solution. I was able to get your desired result.

Comment: there are some changes in question, can you please help?

Comment: dont make it agile pls :P, when full code is there you can apply switch case at least, opening bounty of 50 looks like you are taking our exam and want exact result then only will give 50 marks. community is to help you to solve your prob. not exactly completing your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the object type problem by using the spread operator and Array.prototype.reduce().

```js
const data1 = {
      attributes: [
        {
          Id: "test1",
          Name: "Test1",
          Type: "date",
        },
        {
          Id: "test2",
          Name: "Test2",
          Type: "string",
        },
        {
          Id: "test3",
          Name: "Test3",
          Type: "string",
        },
        {
          Id: "test4",
          Name: "Test4",
          Type: "boolean",
        },
      ],
    };

    const data2 = {
      value: [
        {
          test1: "10-12-2021",
          test2: "4",
        },
        {
          test3: "3",
          test4: true,
        },
        {
          test1: "12-12-2023",
          test3: "42",
        },
      ],
    };

    //function

    const data11 = {
      attributes: [
        {
          Id: "test1",
          Name: "Test1",
          Type: "string",
        },
        {
          Id: "test2",
          Name: "Test2",
          Type: "string",
        },
        {
          Id: "test3",
          Name: "Test3",
          Type: "string",
        },
        {
          Id: "test4",
          Name: "Test4",
          Type: "boolean",
        },
      ],
    };

    const data12 = {
      value: [],
    };

    function mapper(data1, data2) {
      const columns = data1.attributes.reduce((prev, item) => {
        prev[item["Id"]] = item;
        return prev;
      }, {});
      const emptyValues = Object.keys(columns).reduce((prev, item) => {
        prev[columns[item].Name] = "";
        return prev;
      }, {});
      const getValueByType = (key, v) => {
        switch (columns[key].Type) {
          case "boolean":
            return v ? "Y" : "N";
          case "date":
            return new Date(v).toLocaleDateString();
          default:
            return v;
        }
      };

      return {
        rows:
          (data2.value &&
            (data2.value.length == 0
              ? [emptyValues]
              : data2.value.map((row) =>
                  Object.entries(row).reduce(
                    (rlt, [key, v]) => {
                      rlt[columns[key].Name] = getValueByType(key, v);
                      return rlt;
                    },
                    { ...emptyValues }
                  )
                ))) ||
          [],
      };
    }

    const result1 = mapper(data1, data2);
    console.log(result1.rows);
    const result2 = mapper(data11, data12);
    console.log(result2);
```

Comment: it is not checking the types (boolean,date)

Comment: Why does it need to validate? we use the original data value instead of empty string ''

Comment: if you see in expected output I am changing date and boolean data

Comment: instead of "Name" the "Id" is coming in the output, for example instead of test1 it should be "Test1" as per output

Comment: @Bravo I used Name instead of id

Answer (score 0):

@ulou's answer is great!. It can be done using ***reduce***. I updated a source a little.

```
const mapper = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const keys = arr1.attributes.map(item => ({ Id: item.Id, Name: item.Name }));
    const format = e => {
        switch (true) {
            case typeof e === 'boolean': return e ? 'Y' : 'N'
            case isNaN(e) && !isNaN(Date.parse(e)):
                return new Date(e).toLocaleDateString()
            default: return e
        }
    }

    const mapped = (arr2.value ?? [0]).map(item => keys.reduce((prev, cur) => (
        { ...prev, [cur.Name]: format(item[cur.Id] ?? '') }
    ), {}));

    return { rows: mapped };
}

console.log(mapper(data1, data2));
console.log(mapper(data1, []));
```